# Using another SqlCommand in while loop in winform

Tags: c#, sql-server, foreach, while-loop

When I comment the `dr.close`, I get an error

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this command which must be closed first

But when I uncomment the reader, I get this error:

> Invalid attempt to call Read when reader is closed

My code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in datagridtempsale.Rows )
{
    string j = row.Cells[datagridsale.Columns["ItemId"].Index].Value.ToString();
    string k = row.Cells[datagridtempsale.Columns["ItemId"].Index].Value.ToString();

    bool z = k == j;

    if (z == true)
    {
        SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("select TotalQuantity,TAmount from tbl_stock where ItemId=@id", d.con);
        cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",row.Cells[datagridsale.Columns["ItemId"].Index].Value.ToString());

        d.con.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd2.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            int m = int.Parse(dr["TotalQuantity"].ToString());
            decimal n = decimal.Parse(dr["TAmount"].ToString());

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update tbl_stock set TotalQuantity=@tq,TAmount=@ta where ItemId=@id", d.con);

            cmd.Parameters.Clear();

            string g = m.ToString();
            string f = row.Cells[datagridtempsale.Columns["ItemQuantity"].Index].Value.ToString();
            string i = n.ToString();
            string h = row.Cells[datagridtempsale.Columns["TotalPrice"].Index].Value.ToString();

            int x = (int.Parse(g) - int.Parse(f));
            decimal y = (decimal.Parse(i) - decimal.Parse(h));

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tq", x);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ta", y);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", row.Cells[datagridtempsale.Columns["ItemId"].Index].Value.ToString());

            dr.Close();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            d.con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use   dr.Close(); after while loop

Comment: same with   
                                d.con.Close();

Comment: Use the `using`-statement for the connection as well, so don't reuse it but initialize, open, use and close it in this method.

Comment: And for your own sake, don't use single letter variable names. Use meaningfull names. Also, [don't use AddWithValue](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/), And while we're at at, replace `bool z = k == j;  if (z == true)` with `if(k == j)`

Comment: The update command is using the same connection as the open `DataReader` within the `while` loop. You need to either use a different connection object for each `SqlCommand` or use `MultipleActiveResultSets` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/enabling-multiple-active-result-sets) to interleave statement execution.